# unused drink packets

Tags: culinary-uses, drinks

So I have a lot of those drink packets that you just add into a bottle of water and shake.  It's pretty much adult kool-aid.  A while ago my wife and I went a little overboard and bought way too many, which is making me wonder if they have any other uses.  I've used them for making cheap drinks (for those who don't deserve the good booze), but haven't really come up with other uses, so I'm turning to you!

Can anyone come up with any good culinary uses for these things?  They come in all kinds of flavors. I know I have: Lemonade, Strawberry, Orange, Blueberry, Daquiri, and a host of other flavors I can't think of.

Thanks!

Comment: I've played around with this too. The issue I've found is that they are just soooo sweet. Desserts are where you'll need to focus because of that.

Comment: I've actually wondered if it's possible to make something passable as a lemon meringue without using citrus, but only Countrytime Lemonade.  Is that wrong?  (I've had the idea for years, but have never tried)

Answer (score 9):

I have mixed them with unflavored gelatin to get some really interesting flavored deserts.

Additionally, they are a nice addition to a pitcher of iced tea, making it a flavored iced tea.  I use at about 1/2 the recommended strength in addition to the tea, two tubes/packets of the flavored stuff for a 1/2 gallon of tea.

Comment: waaw, "flavored" iced tea FTW!!

Answer (score 3):

You could use these as an aid to shop bought cake mixes, I sometimes use a commercial pound / sponge cake mix. And then make a homemade icing, you could add the powdered sachet to the icing sugar before mixing, you might have to experiment with the amount for flavour.

You could also try adding to the dry cake mix before adding the wet ingredients.  In my mind I'm seeing an orange flavoured cake, then iced with a lemonade icing.

Answer (score 2):

You can eat some - but not all - flavours as coulis on your ice cream (best use vanilla ice cream) or panacotta.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a little Sodium chloride, and somewhat less Potassium chloride you've converted your drink mixes into a Gatorade like sports drink. Recipes are all over the web.

Answer (score 0):

To mute the possibly over sweet qualities, you might try making making some sort of a frozen desset.  If you have an ice cream maker you could go for a sorbet, but if you don't, either a granita, or freeze it in smaller containers with some sort of a stick to make popsicles.

And on the alcohol route ... I had a friend who made something he called 'Agent Orange'.  It was Tang, replacing the amount of water called for with vodka.  (no water at all, just vodka).  I also remember another friend adding various kool-aid powders into mixed drinks.

And my brother brought back a recipe from Pennsic which involved Countrytime Lemonade, some brand of lime vodka (can't remember the exact one, but he was rather specific), and well water ... and he insisted it wasn't the same with tap water.

Comment: This drink (Agent Orange), can you compare it to a Screwdriver?
Maybe you can make cosmopolitans as well :) (By replacing the cranberry juice with a drink packet)

Comment: @Mien : Sorry, no ... I'll have to actually try a screwdriver (and probably an Agent Orange, as it's been ~15 years since I had one) to compare them.

Comment: @Mien As teenagers, this is how we used to start a bottle of vodka when we wanted to get drunk quickly. For the first two drinks, you put in the sweet powder, no matter which flavour, without adding water or some other dilutant. It covered somewhat the strong taste for people who didn't like the taste of pure vodka (and remember, we are talking cheapest discounter-brand alc here, often room temp). The taste is only slightly less terrible than drinking the vodka pure. This is not a cocktail, it is a crutch on the road to being an alcoholic (sadly, several of my classmates completed it).

Answer (score 0):

Daiquiri flavored, hmmm?

Here are my ideas.

- Sno-cones.

Shave  or crush some ice. Mound it using an ice cream scoop.

Sprinkle the powder over the shaved ice.

If you can fashion a paper cone using parchment paper that would be great; if not, just served in a  short coffee mug with a teaspoon for scooping.

We used to do this with a penny candy called Lik-m-Aid when I was a kid.

- Turn them into flavored ice cubes for use in other drinks
- Picking up on the gelatin suggestion above, make Jello shots using
  unflavored gelatin, flavor and vodka. Leave out the vodka and  give
  them to the kids